# Erro com a propriedade checked e value no Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

Estou tentando utilizar um código para obter o valor do radio button selecionado e estou me deparando com os seguintes erros:

> A propriedade 'checked' não existe no tipo 'HTMLElement'.

> A propriedade 'value' não existe no tipo NodeListOf<HTMLElement>.

Segue meu código :

```
getRadioValor(name){
  var rads = document.getElementsByName(name);

  for(var i = 0; i< rads.length; i++){
    if(rads[i].checked){
      return rads.value;
    }
  }
}
```

Qual o motivo desses erros ? E como resolver ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47492595/why-foreach-does-not-exist-on-nodelistof

Comment: Desculpe, mas não consegui entender muito bem o que está causando o erro ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma forma simples que utilizo para pegar o valor checado de `radio`s com **mesmo *name*** em Javascript puro é assim:

```
getRadioValor(name){
  const radioValue = document.querySelector(`input[name = ${name}]:checked`).value;
  console.log(radioValue);
}
```

Como você está utilizando o [angular-material](https://material.angular.io) você deve fazer no evento `change` do `<mat-radio-button>`, dessa forma:

```
<mat-radio-button nome="R0" class="margem" value="1" (change)="getRadioValor($event)"
  0
</mat-radio-button>
```

E o método fica assim:

```
getRadioValor(event) {
 console.log(event.value)
}
```

Comment: está dando erro no .value : "A propriedade 'value' não existe no tipo 'Element'.
Por algum motivo a propriedade .value não é reconhecido no meu arquivo, saberia o por que ?

Comment: `querySelector` retorna um Element porque ele não sabe o que está vindo na query, faça um _cast_, assim: `(document.querySelector(`input[name = ${name}]:checked`) as HTMLInputElement).value;`

Comment: Certo, resolveu o erro do .value, porém, agora quando eu seleciono o radio button e chamo o método getRadioValor, o meu formulário da o seguinte erro : ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Comment: Ele irá dar esse retorno caso não encontre nenhum valor checado, isso inclusive é algo que você precisa tratar depois, mas até quando possui um checado ele continua dando o erro?

Comment: Sim, estou chamando o método no evento (click) do meu radio button, assim se ele for selecionado o método é chamado.

Comment: Segue o código do radio button : 
<mat-radio-button nome="R0" class="margem" value="1" (click)="getRadioValor(R0)">0</mat-radio-button>

Comment: Editei a minha resposta com sua dúvida no Angular Material

Comment: Certo, assim que possível eu ja testo e te dou um retorno .

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado !

Comment: Não se esqueça de marcar como resposta correta. Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

> A propriedade 'checked' não existe no tipo 'HTMLElement'.

Significa que o `name` que você passou não retornou elementos do tipo `radio` ou `checkbox` (são os que contém a propriedade `checked`). Verifique se não existem outros elementos com o mesmo name.

> A propriedade 'value' não existe no tipo NodeListOf.

Você esqueceu o `[i]` para acessar um elemento do NodeList e acabou tentando acessar a propriedade `value` de NodeList ao invés do HTMLElement. Basta mudar:

```
return rads.value;
```

Para:

```
return rads[i].value;
```

Segue um exemplo funcional:

```js
function getRadioValue(name) {
  let radios = document.querySelectorAll(`input[name=${name}]`);
  
  for (let i=0, l=radios.length ; i<l ; i++) {
    let radio = radios[i];
    
    if (radio.checked) return radio.value;
  }
  
}


let btn = document.querySelector('#btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log(getRadioValue('teste'));
});
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="teste" value="1">
  Radio 1
</label>

<label>
  <input type="radio" name="teste" value="2">
  Radio 2
</label>

<label>
  <input type="radio" name="teste" value="3">
  Radio 3
</label>

<br>

<button id="btn">Log selected</button>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado por me esclarecer os erros :)